# Is it possible to record MJPEG directly on Android?

Tags: video, video-recording, ffmpeg, compression

Is it possible to record video from an android camera directly as MJPEG? I am interested in MJPEG for quality purposes. I don't want to record video via default android settings and then convert to MJPEG, but directly from the camera device as MJPEG. Is this possible? I can't find any information suggesting this is possible.

Comment: It's camera app developer's choice, not Android's. You can build a camera app of your own and apply whatever formatting you want while converting raw stream to a video file.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks. Can you provide any examples or tutorials on how to convert the raw stream to a video file? I've already tried initiating the camera with ffmpeg and changing parameters to MJPEG, but the quality of the recorded video makes me think it was recorded and compressed on the device and then my command then converted the already compressed version. How do I get direct access to the raw stream?

Comment: That's a more development related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45577505/9165920, off-topic here. Official documentation would be a good starting point: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.